# Listener doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm writing a Java programm, according to MVC model.

So the problem is that the Frame doesn't react to button click.
(The text, that I write isn't added to the TextArea after click)

At first I call constructors for View and Controller

```
                MessageFrame mf = new MessageFrame(con);
                MessageFrameListener mfl = new MessageFrameListener(mf);
```

Here is the part of MessageFrameListener class   (controller)

```
public class MessageFrameListener{
private MessageFrame mf;

public MessageFrameListener(MessageFrame m_f){
    mf = m_f;
    m_f.addButtonListener(new SButtonListener());
}

//@Override
public class SButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String insert = mf.getInput();
            mf.addLine(insert);
            mf.refreshInput();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the part from MessageFrame class (View)

```
public class MessageFrame{

public JTextField messField;
public JTextArea dialogArea;
public JButton sendButton;
public JFrame frame;
public Contact con;
public MessageFrame (Contact con_get) {
    con = con_get;
    frame = new JFrame();

  frame.setSize(538, 299);

  JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

  JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel_2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  panel_2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

  messField = new JTextField();
  panel_2.add(messField);
  messField.setColumns(10);

  JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
  panel_2.add(sendButton);

  JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel_3, BorderLayout.EAST);

  JPanel panel_4 = new JPanel();
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel_4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  panel_4.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

  JTextArea dialogArea = new JTextArea();
  panel_4.add(dialogArea);
  frame.setVisible(true);


}

public String getInput(){
    return messField.getText();
}

public void refreshInput(){
    messField.setText("");
}

public void addLine(String line){
    dialogArea.append(line);
}

public void addButtonListener(ActionListener bal){
    sendButton.addActionListener(bal);
}


}
```

Comment: I'm trying to accept some questions, but they are likely to be difficult for me

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that comment. You can (if you want to) accept _answers_ to your questions. The first question you asked has an answer, and you commented that that answer works. You could accept that one for example. (That's the way you say "thanks" to the person who helped you best.)

Comment: Sorry, I mistunderstood your comment. I thought your were talking about answering questions. I'll try to accept

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Do you get a button click callback in the debugger if you set a break point in your listener?

Comment: Aftes Visual Studio is easy to make a breakpoint and see results, but how to do it in Eclipse I really don't know. I add a breakpoint even at the begining of main class but nothing happens

Comment: You are missing very important thing, since you adhering to the MVC pattern, why on `GOD's GREEN EARTH` had you declared your fields as `public`, they should be `private or protected` as the case may be, only the `getter/setter` methods need to be public not the fields :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will definately find the answer if you check the output of your program or debug it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test3.MessageFrame.addButtonListener(Main.java:93)
    at test3.MessageFrameListener.<init>(Main.java:28)
    at test3.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Your are hiding the reference to the JButton sendButton by declaring it again in the constructor so the field is never initialised.

```
JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
panel_2.add(sendButton);
```

Comment: About redeclaration, what can you advice?

Comment: Don't do it? Instead of declaring it again `JButton sendButton = new ...` just initilize it `sendButton = new ...`. Just like you do with `messField`

Comment: Thanks! It works. I also modified JTextArea dialogArea = new JTextArea();

Answer (score 2):

Since you've posted code scraps and have not posted a functioning [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that we can test, all we can do is guess -- so you'll get what you paid for, and here goes my guess:

You're listening on the wrong MessageFrame. Your program has 2 or more MessageFrame objects, one of which is displayed, and the other which is being listened to, and so your displayed MessageFrame will of never trip the listener.

If this doesn't help, and you need *better* help, then please provide us with a *better* question, and an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an empty string:

```
String insert = mf.getInput(); //all it does is: messField.getText();
mf.addLine(insert); //adding the empty string
mf.refreshInput(); //all it does is: messField.setText("");
```

Comment: Ah you are manually entering text into that field? Sorry about that then.

Comment: I added a comment in initial answer